# Logging stdout to gunicorn access log?

Tags: flask, gunicorn

When I wrap my Flask application in gunicorn writing to stdout no longer seems to go anywhere (simple `print` statements don't appear). Is there someway to either capture the stdout into the gunicorn access log, or get a handle to the access log and write to it directly?

Comment: I'm finding errors won't appear anywhere whereas `print` statements will provided there are no errors.

Answer (score 17):

Use the logging: set the stream to stdout

```
import logging

app.logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout))
app.logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

app.logger.debug("Hello World")
```

Answer (score 7):

Two solutions to this problem. They are probably longer than others, but ultimately they tap into how logging is done under the hood in Python.

### 1. set logging configuration in the Flask app

The official Flask documentation on logging works for gunicorn. https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/logging/#basic-configuration

- some example code to try out:

```
from logging.config import dictConfig

from flask import Flask

dictConfig(
    {
        "version": 1,
        "disable_existing_loggers": False,
        "formatters": {
            "default": {
                "format": "[%(asctime)s] [%(process)d] [%(levelname)s] in %(module)s: %(message)s",
                "datefmt": "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z"
            }
        },
        "handlers": {
            "wsgi": {
                "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
                "stream": "ext://flask.logging.wsgi_errors_stream",
                "formatter": "default",
            }
        },
        "root": {"level": "DEBUG", "handlers": ["wsgi"]},
    }
)
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    app.logger.debug("this is a DEBUG message")
    app.logger.info("this is an INFO message")
    app.logger.warning("this is a WARNING message")
    app.logger.error("this is an ERROR message")
    app.logger.critical("this is a CRITICAL message")
    return "hello world"
```

- run with `gunicorn`

```
gunicorn -w 2 -b 127.0.0.1:5000 --access-logfile - app:app
```

- request it using curl

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:5000
```

- this would generate the following logs

```
[2020-09-04 11:24:43 +0200] [2724300] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
[2020-09-04 11:24:43 +0200] [2724300] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:5000 (2724300)
[2020-09-04 11:24:43 +0200] [2724300] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2020-09-04 11:24:43 +0200] [2724311] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 2724311
[2020-09-04 11:24:43 +0200] [2724322] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 2724322
[2020-09-04 11:24:45 +0200] [2724322] [DEBUG] in flog: this is a DEBUG message
[2020-09-04 11:24:45 +0200] [2724322] [INFO] in flog: this is an INFO message
[2020-09-04 11:24:45 +0200] [2724322] [WARNING] in flog: this is a WARNING message
[2020-09-04 11:24:45 +0200] [2724322] [ERROR] in flog: this is an ERROR message
[2020-09-04 11:24:45 +0200] [2724322] [CRITICAL] in flog: this is a CRITICAL message
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Sep/2020:11:24:45 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 11 "-" "curl/7.68.0"
```

### 2. set logging configuration in Gunicorn

- same application code as above but without the `dictConfig({...})` section
- create a `logging.ini` file

```
[loggers]
keys=root

[handlers]
keys=consoleHandler

[formatters]
keys=simpleFormatter

[logger_root]
level=DEBUG
handlers=consoleHandler

[handler_consoleHandler]
class=StreamHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=simpleFormatter
args=(sys.stdout,)

[formatter_simpleFormatter]
format=[%(asctime)s] [%(process)d] [%(levelname)s] - %(module)s - %(message)s
datefmt=%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z
```

- run gunicorn with `--log-config logging.ini` option, i.e `gunicorn -w 2 -b 127.0.0.1:5000 --access-logfile - --log-config logging.ini app:app`

Answer (score 2):

The solution from John mee works, but it duplicates log entries in the stdout from gunicorn.

I used this:

```
import logging
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

if __name__ != '__main__':
    gunicorn_logger = logging.getLogger('gunicorn.error')
    app.logger.handlers = gunicorn_logger.handlers
    app.logger.setLevel(gunicorn_logger.level)
```

and got I this from: https://medium.com/@trstringer/logging-flask-and-gunicorn-the-manageable-way-2e6f0b8beb2f

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect standard output to a **errorlog** file, which is enough for me.

Note [that](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#capture-output):

> #### capture_output
>
> `--capture-output`
> `False`
> Redirect stdout/stderr to specified file in **errorlog**

---

My config file `gunicorn.config.py` setting

```
accesslog = 'gunicorn.log'
errorlog = 'gunicorn.error.log'
capture_output = True
```

Then run with `gunicorn app_py:myapp -c gunicorn.config.py`

The equivaluent command line would be

`gunicorn app_py:myapp --error-logfile gunicorn.error.log --access-logfile gunicorn.log --capture-output`