# Logging Flask application with gunicorn

Tags: python-3.x, flask, gunicorn, python-logging

I'm learning python and Flask and now i require some community help.

I've build pretty simple Flask application for my colleagues at my current job. It runs in Docker on Ubuntu machine, behind the nginx, database is Postresql.
The app is served by `gunicorn` with this command.

```
exec gunicorn -b :5000 --access-logfile - --error-logfile - base_habilis:app
```

In general i followed Miguel Grinberg tutorial, with some additions and fixes according Flask and depending libraries documentation and some other sources. It works runs and works well.

Now i stuck with some logging issue. Flask has built-in logger, which logs pretty much all activity.

After that i tried to configure my own log format and add some custom log messages (in error handlers for example), so my issue begins here.

I followed official Flask documentation and added this configuration (which is copy-paste from doc):

```
from logging.config import dictConfig

dictConfig({
    'version': 1,
    'formatters': {'default': {
        'format': '[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s in %(module)s: %(message)s',
    }},
    'handlers': {'wsgi': {
        'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        'stream': 'ext://flask.logging.wsgi_errors_stream',
        'formatter': 'default'
    }},
    'root': {
        'level': 'INFO',
        'handlers': ['wsgi']
    }
})

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    # and all other inits
```

There is my 404 error handler

```
def save_logs(error):
    current_app.logger.info('Failed endpoint - ' + request.url)
    current_app.logger.error(error.code, exc_info=True)

@bp.app_errorhandler(NotFound)
def not_found_error(error: NotFound):
    save_logs(error)
    response = {
        'code': error.response['ResponseMetadata']['HTTPStatusCode'],
        'message': error.response['Error']['Message'],
        'tb': traceback.format_exc()
    }
    return render_template('errors/base_error.html', response=response)
```

If i run this flask app with built in dev server `flask run` - everything works well: i see full log output in my new formatting.

```
[2023-10-09 11:40:23,680] INFO in _internal: 127.0.0.1 - - [09/Oct/2023 11:40:23] "GET /das HTTP/1.1" 404 -
[2023-10-09 11:40:23,701] INFO in _internal: 127.0.0.1 - - [09/Oct/2023 11:40:23] "GET /static/styles.css HTTP/1.1" 304 -
[2023-10-09 11:40:23,722] INFO in _internal: 127.0.0.1 - - [09/Oct/2023 11:40:23] "GET /static/sad_face.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
[2023-10-09 11:40:44,726] INFO in _internal: 127.0.0.1 - - [09/Oct/2023 11:40:44] "GET /index HTTP/1.1" 200 -
[2023-10-09 11:40:44,751] INFO in _internal: 127.0.0.1 - - [09/Oct/2023 11:40:44] "GET /static/styles.css HTTP/1.1" 304 -
[2023-10-09 11:40:44,756] INFO in _internal: 127.0.0.1 - - [09/Oct/2023 11:40:44] "GET /static/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 304 -
[2023-10-09 11:40:54,009] INFO in handlers: Failed endpoint - some_endpoint
[2023-10-09 11:40:54,010] ERROR in handlers: 404
Traceback (most recent call last):
#etc
```

But if i run it with gunicorn, it runs okay, but i can only see logs of my custom error handlers (and prints as well)

```
[2023-10-09 12:26:28 +0300] [8286] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 21.2.0
[2023-10-09 12:26:28 +0300] [8286] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:5000 (8286)
[2023-10-09 12:26:28 +0300] [8286] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2023-10-09 12:26:28 +0300] [8287] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 8287
[2023-10-09 12:26:39,413] INFO in handlers: Failed endpoint - some_endpoint
[2023-10-09 12:26:39,414] ERROR in handlers: 404
Traceback (most recent call last):
# blabla
```

The fun thing is, that if i even remove this custom log config - my log messages in error handlers are still keeping this custom format.

```
(venv) antonstrokov@https://base-habilis ia_ras_anthropology % gunicorn -b 127.0.0.1:5000 --access-logfile - --error-logfile - base_habilis:app
[2023-10-09 12:27:58 +0300] [8338] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 21.2.0
[2023-10-09 12:27:58 +0300] [8338] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:5000 (8338)
[2023-10-09 12:27:58 +0300] [8338] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2023-10-09 12:27:58 +0300] [8339] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 8339
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Oct/2023:12:28:03 +0300] "GET /index HTTP/1.1" 200 3952 "some_endpoint" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/17.0 Safari/605.1.15"

# other requests logs in default gunicorn format

# my custom error logs with already removed (!) formatting

[2023-10-09 12:28:13,216] INFO in handlers: Failed endpoint - some_endpoint
[2023-10-09 12:28:13,216] ERROR in handlers: 404
```

It seems to me, that this custom config is stored somewhere in cache and gunicorn doesn't catch request/response logs? At this point of my knowledge i wasn't able to debug this issue by myself.

So, my question is - how can i also log the default flask request/response output with gunicorn and custom logs formatting?

I know, that nginx also logs every request/response and i can get this information from it, but i try to understand

1. how it works
2. i would like to have logs in one format for possible parsing in future

**What i tried so far:**

I tried many options for `stream` in handlers dict like `sys.stdout`, `sys.stderr` etc. - nothing helped

I tried to remove all `pycache` folders and files, then i even removed and reinstalled venv folder (at least trying to understand - why the heck it keeps my custom log format for some log entries?) - the issue persist

I learned from the flask docs, that there is 'werkzeug' logger, which logs this basic req/resp activity. I tried to define it explicitly in my conf with the same handler like that:

```
    'werkzeug': {
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'handlers': ['wsgi']
    }
```

but it won't work either.

I also tried some solutions from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21399680/logging-stdout-to-gunicorn-access-log) - like adding `--capture-output` flag or redefining `gunicorn.error` logger - also no success

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you don’t see `gunicorn access` logs:

> You are overriding the [logging configuration](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.config.html#logging.config.dictConfig) inside gunicorn worker

Let's make a small test:

```
import logging.config

DEFAULT_LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'loggers': {'': {'level': 'DEBUG'}}
}

logging.config.dictConfig(DEFAULT_LOGGING)
logging.debug('DEBUG LEVEL')

# let's change log level and call dictConfig one more time
DEFAULT_LOGGING['loggers']['']['level'] = 'INFO'
logging.config.dictConfig(DEFAULT_LOGGING)

logging.debug('DEBUG LEVEL')
```

You'll see the only one message - `DEBUG:root:DEBUG LEVEL`. The same situation with `gunicorn`:

```
# base_habilis.py
from logging.config import dictConfig
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

dictConfig({'version': 1, 'root': {'level': 'INFO', 'handlers': []}})


@app.route('/test')
def test():
    return 'ok'
```

Run server `gunicorn -p app.pid -w 1 --access-logfile - --capture-output --log-level debug 'base_habilis:app'` and call API from a new terminal:

```
curl http://localhost:8000/test
curl http://localhost:8000/
```

You will not see access logs:

```
[2023-10-16 17:29:18 +0200] [251581] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 21.2.0
[2023-10-16 17:29:18 +0200] [251581] [DEBUG] Arbiter booted
[2023-10-16 17:29:18 +0200] [251581] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (251581)
[2023-10-16 17:29:18 +0200] [251581] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2023-10-16 17:29:18 +0200] [251582] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 251582
[2023-10-16 17:29:18 +0200] [251581] [DEBUG] 1 workers
```

And now let's skip `dictConfig(...)`, restart server and call API again:

```
[2023-10-16 17:31:28 +0200] [252523] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 21.2.0
[2023-10-16 17:31:28 +0200] [252523] [DEBUG] Arbiter booted
[2023-10-16 17:31:28 +0200] [252523] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (252523)
[2023-10-16 17:31:28 +0200] [252523] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2023-10-16 17:31:28 +0200] [252524] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 252524
[2023-10-16 17:31:28 +0200] [252523] [DEBUG] 1 workers
[2023-10-16 17:31:32 +0200] [252524] [DEBUG] GET /test
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Oct/2023:17:31:32 +0200] "GET /test HTTP/1.1" 200 2 "-" "curl/7.81.0"
[2023-10-16 17:31:35 +0200] [252524] [DEBUG] GET /
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Oct/2023:17:31:35 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 207 "-" "curl/7.81.0"
```

So you just reset [gunicorn logger configuration](https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/blob/21.x/gunicorn/glogging.py)(see: `Logger.setup()` method or `dictConfig` usage).

---

> How to fix the problem

1. You can configure the application logger without `dictConfig` usage
2. You can set [disable_existing_loggers](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.config.html#logging.config.dictConfig) to *False*. `dictConfig({'disable_existing_loggers': False, ...})`

Comment: Thx a lot! Yeah, i saw already, that without dictConfig it works well. But the problem is, that i can't change those access logs standard formatting. I suppose i should dive more deep in the `gunicorn` configs.

disable_existing_loggers didn't worked out though...

Comment: @AntonStrokov [here is the setting](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#access-log-format)